# Error in querying data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I have a mapserver file as below , I get blank page with no map executing this query:

```
   NAME         var
     DATA         xyz
     STATUS       ON
     TYPE         POINT
     DUMP    TRUE
     CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
     CONNECTION  "user=xx password=xxxx dbname=xxx host=xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
     DATA "the_geom from (select * from xyz) as temp using unique id using SRID=xxxx"       
     TEMPLATE    spwms.html
     CLASS
       NAME       "test"
       STYLE
         SYMBOL     'circle'
         SIZE          5
         COLOR        255 0 0
       END
     END
   END # ends here
```

The query is to get all tuples from a table called xyz:

```
DATA "the_geom from (select * from xyz) as temp using unique id using SRID=xxxx"
```

I get a blank page with missing picture Icon on the page. What could be the error here?

Comment: when I use symbol 'circle' I get an error (a blank page)

Comment: A blank page does not necessarily mean there is an error, unless you see an error message. Consider [debugging MapServer](http://mapserver.org/optimization/debugging.html) to get more incite.